# How to add lua operators to vim syntax file?

Tags: vim, syntax, lua

I'm a Lua developer. My development environment is SSH into a central server and using VIM.

Vim comes with the following Lua [syntax file.](http://jmulro-stuff.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/DisputeSettlement/tools/vim/lua.vim)

What I noticed is the syntax file does not include [Relational Operators](http://www.lua.org/pil/3.2.html) (e.g.: =, >, etc) and instead treats relational operators as normal text syntax (color).

I tried adding the following to my `.vim/after/syntax/lua.vim` but it didn't work

```
syn keyword luaOperator < > <= >= == ~=
```

Any ideas how I can make relational operators a different syntax color in Lua?

Comment: By the way: the syntax file you linked is ancient. You might want to pull the latest version from Vim's source control. (The operators are still not highlighted though.)

Comment: @glts, so if the current syntax file doesn't define the operators - so you have any idea how too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

By reading [this article](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/46.html), I figured out how to get VIM to syntax highlight the following Lua operators: `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `==`, `~=`, `=`.

Put the following in your `.vim/after/syntax/lua.vim` file

```
syntax match potionOperator "<"
syntax match potionOperator ">"
syntax match potionOperator "<="
syntax match potionOperator ">="
syntax match potionOperator "=="
syntax match potionOperator "\v\~\="
syntax match potionOperator "="
highlight link potionOperator Operator
```

Then to set the operator to whatever color you want, in your `.vimrc` file put:

```
hi potionOperator ctermfg=COLOR
```

where `COLOR` is whatever color you want (e.g. yellow, red, etc)

Comment: You can drop all but one of the slashes if you remove the all the `\v` (`:h magic`)

Comment: @FDinoff, can you explain your comment in more detail. I'm not following what you're saying. If you have a simpler solution, please make it an answer and I'll mark your answer as the accepted response.

Comment: Its not really simpler but you can change `syntax match potionOperator "\v\<"` to `syntax match potionOperator "<"`. The `\v` turns on very-magic regex and all characters except `0-9,A-Z,a-z,_` have a special meaning which is why you have to escape `<` in your match statement. This removes a lot of slashes and makes it look better. The only character you need to escape is `~`. Also the third and forth match statements don't do what you think their doing because the escaping was not done properly. The only reason it works is because the `<` and `=` are matched separately in two different rules.